# wget, download linked files with specific ending

Tags: wget, download

Want to download all wordlists from this site https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords

I tried

```
wget https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords --no-check-certificate --accept "*.bz2" -r
```

but does only download the targeted page..

What didn't work either:

```
wget https://downloads.skullsecurity.org/passwords/ --no-check-certificate -m
```

(tried different combinations of -m and -r)

Tried also with `--user-agent` to prevent wget preventing from downloading

Tried `-l 3`, still no success..facepalm

Comment: Dear webmaster of skullsecurity, I'm sorry having to ignore your robots.txt but I was too lazy to wget all the single files and I'm really no robot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 wget -e robots=off -r -np -nH --accept "*.bz2"  http://downloads.skullsecurity.org/passwords/
```

Read about [Robot Exclusion](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html)

> If you know what you are doing and really really wish to turn off the robot exclusion, set the robots variable to ‘off’

Site http://downloads.skullsecurity.org/ contains [robot.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) with content

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Explanation

> The `Disallow: /` tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.